# How to write a proof directly from the definition of derivative as a limit without using any of the differentiation rules?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have a practice problem I have worked through but don't have an answer for it. How would you answer this?

Let a ∈ R. Let f be a function which is differentiable at a. Assume that f is always
positive. We define a new function g by g(x) = 1/
f(x)
. Prove that g is differentiable
at a and that
g
0
(a) = −f
0
(a)
(f(a))2
.
Write a proof directly from the definition of derivative as a limit without using any
of the differentiation rules (such as quotient rule or chain rule).

---

[image]

Comment: What is the definition of the derivative?  What have you tried?  Please do **not** respond in the comments, but instead, edit your query to show your work.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a common denominator. Definition of $f'(x)$ is $\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$

$$g'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{f(x+h)} - \frac{1}{f(x)}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(x+h)}{f(x)f(x+h)}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\left(\frac{f(x)-f(x+h)}{h}\right)}{f(x)f(x+h)}$$

Use the quotient limit law and factor out -1 from the numerator. Then the above is equivalent to

$$\frac{\displaystyle-\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)}{\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0}\left(f(x)f(x+h)\right)}$$

Replacing x with a we have

$$\frac{\displaystyle-\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\right)}{\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0}\left(f(a)f(a+h)\right)}$$

The numerator is equivalent to $-f'(a)$. The denominator is equivalent to $(f(a))^2$ as the second factor is a limit of a composite function and $\lim_{h \to 0} (a + h) = a$ so $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(f(a+h)\right) = f(a)$ (since $f$ is continuous at $a$ since it is differentiable at a). As the quotient of two limits that exist $g'(a)$ exists and is equivalent to $\frac{-f'(a)}{(f(a))^2}$

Comment: Are there other ways this can be done? What I did looks a little different (Not sure if that's ok).

Comment: Maybe. You should post what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$g(x+h)-g(x)={1\over f(x+h)}-{1\over f(x)}={f(x)-f(x+h)\over f(x+h) f(x)}\ ,$$
and therefore
$${g(x+h)-g(x)\over h}=-{1\over f(x+h)f(x)}\cdot{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}\ .$$
Now take the limit $h\to0$, and use that $f$ is continuous at $x$.